# Dispatch events in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I needed a simple and efficient way to use events in my JavaScript code, so I came up with a small event library.

Currently, I'm doing it like this:

```
// eva.js - The lightweight es6 event library.
var eva = (() => {
  // Prepare local globals
  var eva = {};
  var receivers = [];
  var gid = 0;
  /**
   * Verify the type of a parameter.
   * Throw if the type does not match the expected type.
   * @param {object} item - The argument itself
   * @param {string} name - The name of the argument
   * @param {string} expected - The expected type
   */
  var verifyType = (item, name, expected) => {
    if (typeof (item) !== expected) {
      throw "Argument '" + name + "' has to be of type '" + expected + "'.";
    }
  }
  /**
   * Subscribe to an event.
   * @param {string} name - The name of the event
   * @param {function} action - The event action
   * @returns {number} - The subscription identifier
   */
  var subscribe = (name, action) => {
    verifyType(name, 'name', 'string');
    verifyType(action, 'action', 'function');
    receivers.push({name: name, action: action, id: gid});
    return gid++;
  }
  /**
   * Unsubscribe from an event.
   * @param {number} id - The subscription identifier
   * @returns {boolean} - Whether the subscription has been removed
   */
  var unsubscribe = id => {
    verifyType(id, 'id', 'number');
    var result = false;
    receivers.every((item, index, arr) => {
      if (item['id'] === id) {
        arr.splice(index, 1);
        result = true;
      }
      return !result;
    });
    return result;
  }
  /**
   * Dispatch an event.
   * @param {string} name - The name of the event
   * @param {object} e - The event data
   */
  var dispatch = (name, e) => {
    verifyType(name, 'name', 'string');
    receivers
      .filter(item => name === item['name'])
      .forEach(item => item['action']({event: name, data: e}));
  };
  /**
   * List all receivers.
   * @returns {array} - The receivers
   */
  var list = () => receivers;
  /**
   * Clear all receivers.
   */
  var clear = () => {
    receivers.length = 0;
  };
  // Make functions accessible
  eva.subscribe = subscribe;
  eva.unsubscribe = unsubscribe;
  eva.dispatch = dispatch;
  eva.clear = clear;
  eva.list = list;
  // Return eva object
  return eva;
}());
module.exports = eva;
```

Since I usually don't write JavaScript code and don't know any best practices and quirks of that language, constructive criticism would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Question: Doesn't this call _all_ event handlers regardless of what event name you're dispatching? Is that intended? If so, what's the point of subscribing to an event by name?

Comment: @Flambino That behavior was not intended, thanks for pointing it out. Fixed it

Comment: You would use a name - that makes perfect sense. What I meant was that it didn't make sense to _subscribe_ to a specific name, if the receiver will get called for all other events too. I just didn't know if that was intentional, or if it was a bug

Comment: @Flambino Yeah I misread your answer. Updated my previous answer to reflect that

Answer (score 1):

It's not bad, though there are some things I'd do different.

Firstly, I'd use a map of arrays for receivers. Doesn't have to be a `Map` instance, a simple object literal will do. For instance, `subscribe` would look like this:

```
var receivers = {};

var subscribe = (name, callback) => {
  if(typeof callback === 'function') {
    receivers[name] = (receivers[name] || []);
    receivers[name].push(callback);
  } else {
    throw new TypeError("callback must be a function");
  }
}
```

This makes it simple to dispatch events:

```
var dispatch = (name, data) => {
  receivers[name].forEach(receiver => receiver({name: name, data: data}));
}
```

Secondly, I wouldn't use rely on a `gid` value to track receivers; I'd use the receiver itself. It eliminates needing to track multiple IDs if one function is subscribing to multiple events, and it makes the sub/unsub functions "symmetrical": All you need is an event name and a function.

```
function someHandler() { ... }

eva.subscribe('someEvent', someHandler);
eva.unsubscribe('someEvent', someHandler);
```

To achieve this, `unsubscribe` could look like:

```
var unsubscribe = (name, callback) => {
  if(receivers[name]) {
    receivers[name] = receivers[name].filter((receiver) => receiver !== callback);
  }
}
```

Also, one important note: Your `list` function returns a reference to the `receivers` array. I don't know if this is intended, but it does mean, that you'd be modify the otherwise-"private" array. For instance, saying `eva.list().push("foobar")` will cause problems, because it sidesteps all you type-checking, and adds something to the array that your code isn't expecting.

Frankly, I don't know how useful the `list` function is to begin with, but in your current code, you could *halfway* fix the issue by simply calling `slice()` on the `receivers` array. That'll create a copy, and return that instead:

```
var list = () => receivers.slice();
```

However, the contents of the copied array will be references to the same objects that are in "private" `receivers` array, so you cause mischief:

```
eva.list()[0].action = "foobar"; // obviously not a proper callback
```

You could spend the time doing a deep clone of everything, but... eh.

Again, simpler to let the array only contain functions. Even if they're returned as references in a copied array, it's harder to accidentally break things.

If you use an object/map to hold the receivers as I suggest above, you do have to do some more complex cloning to return it safely (although the arrays it contains can be copied safely with `slice`). However, I'd just scope everything in the API to a `name`, including `list` and `clear`:

```
var list = (name) => receivers[name] ? receivers[name].slice() : [];

var clear = (name) => receivers[name] = [];
```

If you want to could add a method to return all registered event names by using `Object.keys(receivers)`.

You'll note that I haven't bothered much with type-checking. Only when subscribing do I check that the callback is actually a function. But `name` arguments? Don't really care.

Type-checking isn't super necessary in JS. Often it really doesn't matter due to type coercion, or you explicitly cast/parse if you need to. Other times it's just simpler to say "garbage in, garbage out": If someone really wants to use a float as an event name, let them. And let them sort it out, if things don't work. This is what I usually lean toward. Since JS isn't strictly typed (and sometimes plain weird), the effort spent implementing your own type-checking could be spent better elsewhere.

All together, minus comments:

```
var eva = (() => {
  var receivers = {};

  var subscribe = (name, callback) => {
    if(typeof callback === 'function') {
      receivers[name] = (receivers[name] || []);
      receivers[name].push(callback);
    } else {
      throw new TypeError("callback must be a function");
    }
  }

  var unsubscribe = (name, callback) => {
    if(receivers[name]) {
      receivers[name] = receivers[name].filter((receiver) => receiver !== callback);
    }
  }

  var dispatch = (name, data) => {
    receivers[name].forEach(receiver => receiver({name: name, data: data}));
  }

  var list = (name) => receivers[name] ? receivers[name].slice() : [];

  var clear = (name) => receivers[name] = [];

  return {
    subscribe: subscribe,
    unsubscribe: unsubscribe,
    dispatch: dispatch,
    list: list,
    clear: clear
  };
}());
```

Comment: As always quite impressive

Comment: @konijn Thank you - that's dangerously high praise :)